# Sharepoint 2010 foundation, read permissions are blocking users from viewing documents

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I have been receiving complaints that users in at least one of our SharePoint sites are unable to view documents in a list. The list permissions are read access and I have verified those permissions. The only way I can get them access to view documents is to give them edit permissions. Has anyone else seen this? I have gone through the list permissions and advanced settings verify item level permissions and everything checks out.

Comment: folder permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the 'Read' permission level in your site actually has Read Permissions. Follow these steps : Site Settings>Site Permissions>Click 'Permission levels' in ribbon>Click 'Read'>Ensure it has correct list and site permissions for viewing(For example,"View pages in a Web site")

You can also fine tune here how your 'Read' permission level will behave.